# How to place horizontal icons with labels inside a navbar or toolbar - Ionic v2

Tags: ionic2

I have the following code snippet, and I'm trying to create a menu on the top that is a list of icons and a label below each icon.

- The label is in the center of each icon
- The Icons should be in the same row
- All the icons should be placed in the center of the `ion-navbar`

the `ion-toolbar` gives the same behavior as `ion-navbar`

#### ts

```
export class HomePage {
  
  constructor(private nav: NavController) {
  }

  range(min, max, step) {
    var input = [];
        step  = step || 1;    

    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) {
        input.push(i);
    }
    return input;
  }
}
```

#### html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <span  >
    <ion-label *ngFor="let i of range(1,5)"> 
      <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
      Home
    </ion-label>
    </span>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content text-center>
  Some page content
</ion-content>
```

Clean [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jNug7Cj61bEifS0Y7oSc?p=preview),
Worked-on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UoaQEPc622tO0NBcvAOU?p=preview)

Tried to play around but couldn't get the result I need, and I've created the above plunker to have a clean env to play with ...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ion-grid`. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YhEHHeD87FIqUR8dqR8S?p=preview)

**HTML**:

```
 <ion-navbar>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col text-center *ngFor="let i of range(1,5)">
          <ion-label text-center>
            <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
            Home
          </ion-label>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-navbar>
```

**CSS**:

```
ion-label {
  float: none;
}
.toolbar ion-row,
.toolbar ion-col,
.toolbar ion-grid {
  padding: 0px;
}

.toolbar ion-label {
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! will try it out :), but is it ok concept to have `ion-grid` inside a small `ion-navbar` ?

Comment: Trim `ion-grid`, `ion-row` and `ion-col` by setting margin padding 0.

Comment: Thank you for the effort ! much appreciated ! 
I rather not having an `ion-grid` inside a navbar ... seems wrong to me, don't know why .... instead I used:
`ion-label { display: inline-block !important; }`

Comment: That is also fine. Post your solution and accept it, so other can get help from it.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to place them horizontally by adding the following CSS:

```
ion-label {
 display: inline-block !important;
}
```

The key was the `!important` part, as the ion-label is being override by the size of the screen ( like `.md ion-label` etc .. this is why while playing with the Plunker I couldn't get the result I wanted.

Thanks @swapnil-patwa for the help !

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, for Ionic 5 just add this property on `ion-buttons` inside the `ion-toolbar`:

```
flex-direction: column;
```

[image]

Example:

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-button>
            <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-label>User</ion-label>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Comment: thanks, but i gave up on Ionic a long time ago ;) ...